# How to convert a map point string to double?

Tags: c#

I have a string such as 45,5235234096284 or 112,013574120648. I want to convert it to double. I have tried following code but i got error 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetCultureInfo
' because of framework version. I'm not able to change framework option.I have looked some another solution but i couldn't understand clearly.What is the best way converting these string to double with their commas.

```
var convertedMapPoint = double.Parse(mapPoint, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1053));
```

Comment: `var convertedMapPoint = double.Parse("45,5235234096284", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));`

Comment: You want `,` to turn into a decimal?

Comment: I can't use like that because of project code standards.

Comment: How do you want `double` to store for you 2 numbers ? Maybe you meant to store it into 2 variables ?

Comment: No turn into a double. because i will initialize them latitude longitude and they are declared as double. I am not able to change their variable type.

Comment: Is "45,5235234096284 112,013574120648" your only string or is each value its own string?

Comment: They are just examples:) I gave them make people mind clearly.

Comment: Do you mean store both numbers in a single double? i.e latitude in HiWord and longitude in LoWord?

Comment: No they are not. They are diffrent strings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should split your input on spaces, since that is the separator:

```
string input = "45,5235234096284 112,013574120648";
string[] splitted = input.Split(' ');
```

Then you can iterate over the result of the splitting, and convert each to a double:

```
List<double> doubles = new List<double>();

foreach (string s in splitted)
{
    doubles.Add(double.Parse(s, new CultureInfo("fr-FR")));
}
```

I used `fr-fr`, since it has a comma as decimal separator, but you can use any culture that does that.

If that doesn't work for you, and you are 100% sure there is no `.` as thousand separator, you can use this:

```
doubles.Add(double.Parse(s.Replace(",", ".")));
```

Then you might want to add the invariant culture to be platform independent:

```
doubles.Add(double.Parse(s.Replace(",", ".", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

Comment: I'm not able to use ("fr-FR")) statement!

Comment: If not you can also hack your way around it. Let me update.

Answer (score 0):

You should split the string into array delimited by Space, and than convert each part.

```
string mapPoint = "45,5235234096284 112,013574120648";
var mapPoints = mapPoint.Split(' ');
var convertedMapPointX = double.Parse(mapPoints[0], CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1053));
var convertedMapPointY = double.Parse(mapPoints[1], CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1053));
Console.WriteLine("X: {0}\tY: {1}", convertedMapPointX, convertedMapPointY);
```

**Output:**

```
X: 45.5235234096284    Y: 112.013574120648
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StringToMapPoint
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string mapPointStr = "45,5235234096284 112,013574120648";
            MapPoint mp = mapPointStr.ToMapPoint();
            Console.WriteLine(mp.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class MapPoint
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "X: " + X + " Y: " + Y;
        }
    }

    public static class MapPointHelper
    {
        public static MapPoint ToMapPoint(this string str)
        {
            var split = str.Replace(".", ",").Split(' ');
            return new MapPoint() { X = Double.Parse(split[0]), Y = Double.Parse(split[1]) };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't work since `,` is used as a decimal separator.

Comment: Maybe because your culture is set to have a `,` as decimal separator. If that isn't the case, it won't work.

Comment: Now you have it :) With comma :) Just replace the commas in case they are there.